# using varchar over varchar(n) with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, text, varchar

I'm designing a database since I'm not yet comfortable with the data types I was wondering about the following :

If I don't care about the length of a vector of characters, is it appropriate to use **`VARCHAR`**? (even if the strings are expected to be quite short ?)

Until now I've been using **`TEXT`** (`VARCHAR`) when I needed to store really long strings but reading the documentation and asking questions around I heard PostgreSQL does not store the extra bytes if the maximum length is supplied and the stored string's length is lesser than it.
I guess the maximum length is used in case the distant device can't afford large memory space.

Could one agree or explain that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

Comment: so could you say "using text or varchar, even if the expected stored strings are usually short (and can be long as well) is fine if the memory space is not a problem" ?